# Ruby on Rails test "Expected response but returned 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am an experienced web developer and am starting to learn ruby on rails with the use of HTML and CSS tied into the code for rails. I have a test website and am trying to run it on ruby on rails. The test will display a website with a home, help, about, and contact page under one rails application on the web.

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get home" do
     get :home
     assert_response :success
     assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end

   test "should get help" do
     get :help
     assert_response :success
     assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end

  test "should get about" do
     get :about
     assert_response :success
     assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
     get :about
     assert_response :success
     assert_response "title, Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
```

end

However, when I try to run the test on the command prompt, it returns 3 failures on the command prompt. Each of the failures states that the program was expecting a format but received another format of the same type.

```
   FFF.

  Finished in 0.527144s, 7.5881 runs/s, 15.1761 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
    StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about            [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:19]:
   <About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>.
 Expected 0 to be >= 1.


2) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:25]:
Expected response to be a <title, Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>, but was <200>.
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"title, Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
+200



  3) Failure:
     StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13]:
    <Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
    <Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>.
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

How do I fix this within the program? Is there a way to make the program view the code the correct way? If I have to change it, what should I change it to?

Comment: something happened and not all of the code for the ruby file was posted to the website. Here is the ruby code

Comment: can u post the exact error?

Comment: The error is on there now. I have edited the question to display it.

Comment: I have already migrated the application to the database before the error came up, so that is not the issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the exact error?

Answer (score 1):

OK so it means there is no HTML match please see this answer:

[Failure: Expected 0 to be >= 1 on ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945472/failure-expected-0-to-be-1-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: It seems that I have already done those parts within the program, including taking "| Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" off of the application.html.erb file. What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your test

```
test "should get contact" do
   get :about
   assert_response :success
   assert_response "title, Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```

should be

```
test "should get contact" do
   get :contact
   assert_response :success
   assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
```

Other failures are because of title of tested page does not match the expected title in the test, i.e. there's some bug in your app or in the test.

```
  1) Failure:
    StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about            [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:19]:
   <About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>.
 Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Comment: Okay, it works with the contact page. But I'm still receiving an error within the Help section. (It's basically saying the same thing with contact, only with help).

Comment: Well, maybe your titles really do not match? It is expecting `Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App` but found `Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App`.

Comment: I found a bug in the composition of the file formed from its creation in the command prompt, which means I have to recreate the app and write the code again. If the problem comes again, I'll use the answers you provided. Thank you so much, though. It really helped to make me more prepared for any future bugs in the program.