# Ruby giving me similar four failures that other people have had

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, error-handling

I keep getting a few errors that I have seen from other people on here. Here is the error message:

```
   1) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about     [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:19]:
   <About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App.>.
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.


   2) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:25]:
   <Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App.>.
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.


   3) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13]:
   <Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App.>.
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.


   4) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home [C:/Sites/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7]:
   <Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App.>.
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Here is also code for the test file:

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get home" do
      get :home
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end

   test "should get help" do
      get :help
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end

   test "should get about" do
      get :about
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end

   test "should get contact" do
      get :contact
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
   end
 end
```

How do I fix this problem on my application? Do I have to write another part of code for the program?

Comment: By the way, the pages do correspond with the test file.

Comment: It matches this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945472/failure-expected-0-to-be-1-on-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I can't seem to use the information given in the discussion to fix the program of mine, however.

Comment: You can also use this link from a friend of mine who had the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334767/ruby-on-rails-test-expected-response-but-returned-200?noredirect=1#comment54466217_33334767

Comment: When someone asks to see the code that's producing the error, please don't just post a link to someone else's code. That's very unhelpful indeed!

Comment: Did you change the test code for "should get home" before posting it? Are the failure messages still the same?

Comment: Yes, they are. The error message is the same for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding a `.` (period/full stop) after `Sample App` in your tests, or else removing the `.` from your view.

Like this:

```
test "should get home" do
  get :home
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App."
end
```

the message `Expected 0 to be >= 1` simply means the test was counting how many times it could find the content (without the `.`) on the page and it counted 0 but it expected the count to be at least 1 since that is what you assert in you test.

Comment: This is the code for the application.html.erb file                                     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Have you tried doing what I suggest in this answer? What happened?

Comment: Please post the code for you `application.html.erb` file as an edit in your main post. This is absolutely not the place for pasting code.