# Can someone identify the error in my code causing my test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep running this test and it continually fails, yet I cannot find an error. The failure message is:

> [Failure:
>     StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact     [/Users/iThompkins/Documents/SiteDev/environment/sample_app/test/controlle
>   rs/static_pages_controller_test.rb:26]:

```
<Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
<Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.]
```

**My test looks like:**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

   test "should get home" do

    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end

 test "should get help" do
   get static_pages_help_url
   assert_response :success
   assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end

 test "should get about" do
   get static_pages_about_url
   assert_response :success
   assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end

 test "should get contact" do
   get static_pages_contact_url
   assert_response :success
   assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end
end
```

**My controller**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

 def about
 end

 def contact
 end
end
```

**And my View**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
```

## Contact

Contact the Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
  [contact page](http://www.railstutorial.org/contact).

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945472/failure-expected-0-to-be-1-on-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Have you got `<%= yield(:title) %>` in the title section of your view?

`<title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>`

From the [Hartl book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-testing_titles), you need to yield the title value to get it to display.

Comment: my view looks like                                                                                          <% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>
  Contact the Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
  <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
</p>

Comment: What does your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` look like?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>

Comment: <body>    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>